# How to find percentage of three different values?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Say in my table I have three columns `draft`, `live` and `completed`

values are `18` for Draft, `33` for live, `11` for completed

How can I calculate percentage of each in SQL

I tried something like this, but don't think this is calculating correctly

Below is what I tried .. but I think when I try to count the sum of percentage of three they wont cover complete 100

```
UPDATE @finalTable
SET Draft_Percentage =  (CASE
when Draft_Total > 0 then ((Draft_Total * 100) / (select sum(t1.Draft_Total) + sum(t1.Live_Total) + sum(t1.Completed_Total)  from @finalTable as t1))
else 0
end)

UPDATE @finalTable
SET Live_Percentage = (case
WHEN Live_Total > 0 THEN ((Live_Total * 100) / (select sum(t1.Draft_Total) + sum(t1.Live_Total) + sum(t1.Completed_Total) from @finalTable as t1))
else 0
end)

UPDATE @finalTable
SET Completed_Percentage = (CASE
WHEN Completed_Total > 0 THEN ((Completed_Total * 100) / (select sum(t1.Draft_Total) + sum(t1.Live_Total) + sum(t1.Completed_Total) from @finalTable as t1))
else 0
end)
```

Please suggest

Comment: Your question is very unclear. What exactly do you want to calculate? Please provide the definition for @finalTable and also add the tag for the relevant RDBMS.

Comment: c now total objectives now i have is 18+33+11=62. but now what i want to find out the percentage they share out of 100. I am using google stacked bar chart which take till 100 there i want to display these information

Answer (score 1):

So this is basically a math problem and not a programming problem. One way to solve it is to multiply everything with the ratio between 100 and the sum (in your case - 62):
**(18 * (100/62)) + (33 * (100/62)) + (11 * (100/62)) = 62 * (100 / 62)** (that's obviously equal to 100)

Answer (score 0):

What I understand is:-

```
SELECT (18*100)/(18+33+11) AS 'Draft'
     , (33*100)/(18+33+11) AS 'Live'
     , (11*100)/(18+33+11) AS 'Completed'
```

Result

```
Draft       Live    Completed
29          53      17
```